# How to Understand Quantum Phase Slips in Josephson Junction Array in terms of Tunneling?

Tags: electric-circuits, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-tunneling, josephson-junction

I am trying to understand quantum phase slips in terms of quantum tunneling between the minima of the Josephson potential (see [page 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0539.pdf) right before equation (1)). Consider the following circuit diagram of one real Josephson junction (JJ). Here the top circuit element is an ideal JJ which follows the Josephson equations.

[image]

Using the Josephson relations, I obtained the following differential equation. Here $\gamma$ represents the phase difference across the JJ. This can be obtained from Kirchhoff's current law.

$$\bigg(\frac{\hbar}{2e}\bigg)^2 C \frac{d^2 \beta}{dt^2} + \bigg(\frac{\hbar}{2e}\bigg)^2\frac{1}{R} \frac{d\beta}{dt} = -\frac{\hbar I_c}{2e} \sin \beta \equiv - \frac{\partial U(\beta)}{\partial \beta}$$

This equation is similar to a mechanical system involving one particle moving with two applied forces: a frictional force that depends on velocity and a conservative driving force. The mass of this particle is $\big(\frac{\hbar}{2e}\big)^2 C$, the frictional term is $-\big(\frac{\hbar}{2e}\big)^2\frac{1}{R} \frac{d\beta}{dt}$, and the driving force is $-\frac{\hbar I_c}{2e} \sin \beta$

We can think of $\beta$ as the "position" of a phase difference "particle" moving in a potential $U(\gamma)$ called the Josephson potential. Josephson potential is
$$U(\beta) = -\frac{\hbar I_c}{2e}\cos \beta$$

Now, I know that the phase and the excess charge are conjugate variables and thus lead to an uncertainty principle. Suppose the uncertainty in the phase is large. **Does this allow the phase difference to tunnel through the potential barrier of the Josephson potential? If not, how does one explain quantum phase slips as tunneling through the minima of the Josephson potential?**